# What alignment (Law-Chaos-Neutral Axis) would best fit for a Riftwarden

Tags: pathfinder-1e, alignment

I want to play a [riftwarden](http://pathfinderwiki.com/wiki/Riftwardens) and I am not sure what alignment would fit best. The description says:

> The Riftwardens are a loose collection of planar travelers from across
>   the Great Beyond who guard the multiverse's integrity and stability.
>   They aim to prevent evildoers from using planar gateways and punish
>   any who they catch trying.

First off I thought he is lawful since preventing evildoers from using planar gateways and punish them looks lawful to me but I am not sure if I obey any authority since are a rather loose collection and do not obey a authority. So I am not sure about this anymore.

I am not sure what way to go and need some help here.

Comment: Do not answer in comments.

Comment: I've closed this because "what alignment should X be" questions are inherently subjective and you won't get any benefit from the community's expertise, you'll just get random opinions.  See http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/5357/what-kinds-of-alignment-questions-are-on-topic

Comment: @mxyzplk Would rephrasing the question as *What alignments do Riftwardens possess according to official material?* or the like be acceptable?

Comment: A bit listy, but there's only three published riftwardens I know of, so maybe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The Riftwardens are a loose collection of planar travelers from across the Great Beyond who **guard the multiverse's integrity and stability**.

This sounds a lot like the [Inevitables](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/outsiders/inevitable), lawful constructs-like outsiders that fight against chaos.

The group's description only says *non-evil* though, so any aligment, as long as it isn't evil, should be accept on their ranks. But i would say that a **lawful** character would fit more with their ideals.

Considering that their sworn enemies, the [Blackfire Adepts](http://pathfinderwiki.com/wiki/Blackfire_Adepts) are *non-good*, i would say that the perfect "member" for the Riftwardens would be a **lawful good** character.

But any combination of aligment is valid, that will depend on how much you want to commit on fighting against their sworn enemies and towards the goal of the organization. If we say that the Riftwardens is a Neutral Good organization, that allows members from any aligment within *two steps* of it (Lawful good, Lawful neutral, neutral, chaotic good, chaotic neutral), except for neutral evil.